# Expanding visible page area in Expression Blend

Tags: windows-phone-7, layout, expression-blend, visibility

I am using Expression Blend for Windows Phone development. If I insert a layout (grid, stackpanel..) that expands LayoutRoot I cannot see the controls beyond the border. 
Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Trying to visualize what you're seeing here. So would an example be adding a `StackPanel` to a page, then adding 50 stacked `Button` elements so that `LayoutRoot` extends beyond the bottom of the designer screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your PhoneApplicationPage XAML, you should see in the first tag:

```
d:DesignWidth="480"
```

and

```
d:DesignHeight="800"
```

You can manipulate these to extend the design surface to something that lest you see everything.  This will have no effect on the runtime version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your top level control in the Objects and Timeline panel.  Now you should be able to drag the sides/corners to shrink and expand the control's area.  This affects just the size of your control on the design surface, not the runtime size (assuming you've set width and height to Auto).